# How to create vc_col-sm-5 and vc_col-sm-7 custom layout in WPBakery?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wpbakery

I am using the WPBackey plugin. I want to create custom layout `vc_col-sm-5` and `vc_col-sm-7`.

What number I have to use here

[image]

`1/2 + 1/2` is for `vc_col-sm-6 and vc_col-sm-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 5/12 and 7/12 for create a  vc_col-sm-5 and vc_col-sm-7 custom layout in WPBakery